# Build an app with marionettejs with requirejs?

Tags: marionette

I have used backbone boilerplate on the past 
https://github.com/backbone-boilerplate/backbone-boilerplate
I want to use marionette on my next project and I have found this
https://github.com/BoilerplateMVC/Marionette-Require-Boilerplate

My question is if it's a good idea to go with the marionette boilerplate or start form scratch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an aside, I'd like to suggest you give Yeoman a shot for scaffolding your first Marionette app. Yeoman works via what are called "generators", and provide much more than the the above Boilerplate MVC can offer you (Chai and Sinon for testing, Bower for client-side package management, etc...). Plus, Addy Osmani, who runs [backbone-boilerplates](https://github.com/addyosmani/backbone-boilerplates) is one of the heads of the project.  Check out [generator-marionette here.](https://github.com/mrichard/generator-marionette)

Comment: Thanks generator-marionette looks a good solution for me do you know if there is further documentation for it or a tutorial for building an app with it.

Comment: [The Yeoman documentation](http://yeoman.io/) is a great place to start, as it is primary concerned with getting your app's foundation as rock solid as possible before you start work. Thus, there isn't a great deal of Marionette-specific documentation, but great resources on building a modern, modular app, within which you have total freedom to play around with Marionette. Hope that helps!

Comment: @pet generator-marionette is indeed a good solution especially since it assist you in minifying your project via grunt and grunt-contrib-requirejs (don't be affraid of all those tools if you don't know them, they'll only make your frontend development much better and faster in the end :-D).

Comment: @RyanMiller Sorry for my ignorance, but could you tell me what is that 'brew' command from the instructions? Running it from a windows 8 console only tells me that it is not a recognized command.

Comment: @darksoulsong `brew` is a command to initialize Homebrew, a package manager for Mac OSX. Hence why Windows 8 would have some difficulties. You can learn about it [here](http://brew.sh/), and I recommend looking for Windows installs of PhantomJS and MongoDb.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used BoilerPlate, but glancing through it, it certainly seems like a valid approach to writing Marionette apps. If you're just getting started it will certainly help you see how the various pieces are supposed to be used. One gripe I've got is the folder structure. I prefer to break my applications down into modules, and then add models, collections, views, etc under each module. But this will certainly get you up and running quick, and there's nothing stopping you from customizing it to suit your needs.

Comment: Same here, Chris. I just build the app with `grunt` from a modular folder structure.

Comment: Is there any template or example of a module per file marionette application ?

Comment: I wouldn't expect you need to do anything complicated. Let's see if I can paste in a sample:
`define(['backbone'], function( Backbone ) {
    'use strict';
    var View = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({ /* blah */ });
    return View;
});`

Answer (score 0):

I agree with others here: it is a useless limitation to imitate a folder structure that follows the 'old mvc model for server-side code'. You will remain more flexible further down the road if you think of your application strictly as completely self-containing modules, i.e. they contain their own controller/router/views/collections/templates etc. You can have a separate folder structure for shared code that is not a module, although anything can be made a module :)

Regarding boilerplate code and generators: i think in the beginning you should actually NOT do it, because you won't understand what you're doing. But that's just my personal opinion.